# JQuery Datatables : Not Full Size in Card

Tags: datatables

We are using DataTables.Net within a Bootstrap Card. The card is initially collapsed. The grid is as small as possible. We can fix by choosing the page size and it will expand. If the Card is not collapsed it loads just fine. How can I add code to automatically reload on the click of the card or even better just get it to load the full size when the card is collapsed?

```
<!-- Begin: LogFile -->
```

```
    <div class="card-tools">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" data-animation-speed="500"><i class="fal fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table id="dataTableLogFile" class="table table-hover table-striped text-responsive nowrap" style="width: 100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>View</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Payload</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Postal Code</th>
                        <th>Lat/Long</th>
                        <th>Created</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screen Sample]

Comment: Please post a snippet of your JS code

Comment: We can't guess where the problem is coming from if you don't share more code. As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/us9cofxq/), Datatables with collapsed cards works properly. I'd suggest creating a snippet and putting the effort into reproducing your problem for us if you really want to get help.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error the below is working perfectly in every web browser (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari, etc). This appears to be the fix that everyone would need. The key is the hide.bs.collapse which runs AFTER the card is fully extended.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('button').on('click', (event) => {
            $('hide.bs.collapse', (event) => {
                $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
                    .columns.adjust()
                    .responsive.recalc()
                    .scroller.measure()
                    .fixedColumns().relayout();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```